# Python Tkinter GUI messy printing format

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tkinter, format

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

textBox = Text(master, height=1, width=10)
textBox.grid(row=0, column=1)

fileVar = StringVar()
fileLabel = Label(master, textvariable=fileVar)
fileLabel.grid(row=3, column=1)

fileVar2 = StringVar()
fileLabel2 = Label(master, textvariable=fileVar)
fileLabel2.grid(row=3, column=2)

def retrieve_input():
    Customer = textBox.get("1.0","end-1c") 

    fileread = pd.read_csv('50.csv', encoding='latin-1')
    filevalue = fileread.loc[fileread['Customer'].str.contains(Customer, na=False),"Jul-18\nQty"]
    productheader = fileread.loc[fileread['Customer'].str.contains(Customer, na=False), 'Product']    

    fileVar.set(productheader)
    fileVar2.set(filevalue)

button1 = Button(master,text="Show Values", command=lambda: retrieve_input())
button1.grid(row=4, column=1)

mainloop()
```

I have this program that prints values in  Tkinter Gui, for specific values in a specific row. However the format of the values being printed is quiet messy and I am unsure how to clean it up, In addition I would like for it to not display the numbers labeled next to it, Just the product name (blurred out in blue) and the value associated with it( which are the number values with decimals).

Here is a snapshot of the GUI:

[image: TkinterGUI]

In addition, at the very bottom of the list, this is also displayed:

[image: Endofvalues]

Ideally, I would like for it to only show the header(July-18) and not the datatype

Also if it helps to know, these are forecast files, (reason for headers with dates)

Here is a dummy image of what my csv files look like:

[image]

Comment: Your example uses `master` but you never declare what `master` is. I assume this is the `Tk()` instance? Also change `command=lambda: retrieve_input()` to `command=retrieve_input`. You do not need the lambda.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Yes it is! I just added that in. And, this code is part of a much larger code, and I had to condense it to display here. In actuality I have several user inputs and the lamda function is the only way the original code runs

Comment: That's fine but for the purposes of your example code its not needed. Can we get an example row from your CSV. This way we can actually test the code.

Comment: It does not have to be your real data. Just something in the same format we can work with. Also your blue scribbles are not really hiding the data. I can zoom and read. Its best to just delete the values in the column then do a screen cap and then undo your deletion.

Comment: Hum. When I try to convert `filevalue` to a list I only get the numbers from the Jul-18 column but nothing else. This one might be tricky to work with inside of a text box. You may need to read data per cell in each row and use a list to track them then evenly place that data into a text box or some labels.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Yes it was my mistake by trying to oversimplify the problem while posting it here, I just edited my question to also show my code for showing the product header. I am not sure if that would make a difference

Comment: I left for lunch but I will look when I get back.

Comment: @Mike-SMT in addition, the lambda function is necessary to specify the Customer, without it, the program runs without a user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after some testing I think I have found a fix that should work for you.

The main issue with spacing inside of your label is the problem with your font not being one that is considered monospace.

Try using the font `Consolas` and see how well that fixes your layout.

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *


master = Tk()

textBox = Text(master, height=1, width=10, font=('Consolas', 12))
textBox.grid(row=0, column=1)

fileVar = StringVar()
fileLabel = Label(master, textvariable=fileVar, font=('Consolas', 12))
fileLabel.grid(row=3, column=1)

def retrieve_input():
    department = textBox.get("1.0","end-1c") 
    fileread = pd.read_csv('50.csv', encoding='latin-1')
    filevalue = fileread.loc[fileread['Customer'].str.contains(department, na=False),("Jul-18\nQty", "Product")]

    fileVar.set(filevalue)

button1 = Button(master,text="Show Values", command=lambda: retrieve_input())
button1.grid(row=4, column=1)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your welcome. I am not aware of any other way to correct spacing issues inside of a big label string other than trying to record all the data into a list and reformatting the string to your needs. But if fixing the font works for you then that is great.